# cannot import numpy in idle (2.7) after anaconda installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I've installed numpy from the following link http://www.scipy.org/install.html
After installation the paths are defined (verified with `which -a python`)

```
/Users/user_name/Documents/anaconda/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

when open idle 2.7 and try to import numpy I get the following error message

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

So you have several python installations going; which one is idle using?
This should get you pointed in the correct direction for finding modules:
  http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path
(Tweak the version number in that URL as appropriate.)
If that doesn't help, then the list of Related questions, to the right, currently has this as the first hit, and it looks useful too.